# How to configure an external SOAP service in a net core 2.2 project

Tags: wcf, soap

I have a project developed in .net core 2.2.
You need to use a WCF in .Net Framework.
The inclusion of WCF and Reference.cs went well. The service is Ok, as a connected service.
However I am getting a dependency injection error:

`microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicelookup.callsite factory.create argument callsite(type servicetype, type implementationtype, callsitechain callsitechain, parameterinfo[] parameters, bool throwifcallsitenotfound)`

Performing searches on the internet, some answers were related to the configuration of Startup.cs and Program.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
         services
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = this.GetJsonSerializerContractResolver();
                    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = this.GetJsonSerializerDateFormatString();
                });
         this.ConfigureIoC(services);
}

private void ConfigureIoC(IServiceCollection services)
{
         this.ConfigureHelpers(services);
         this.ConfigureUnitOfWorks(services);
         this.ConfigureFacades(services);
         this.ConfigureBusinessServices(services);
         this.ConfigureServiceFilters(services);
         this.ConfigureRestConsumers(services);
}

private void ConfigureHelpers(IServiceCollection services)
{
         services.AddScoped(typeof(IHpUrl), typeof(HpUrl));
         services.AddScoped(typeof(IHpArvoreProduto), typeof(HpArvoreProduto));
}
```

My doubt is whether I would need only one method:

```
private void ConfigureSoaps(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddScoped(typeof(ISoapBla), typeof(SoapBla));
}
```

Since in some responses from the Web, the use of SoapCore among other solutions has been suggested.

Comment: How is it related to C programming ? you tagged it with 'c'. please remove it

Comment: Are you using the SOAPCore class library to create a SOAP service in a Core project, or consuming the service? You can fully refer to the sample Settings in the class library project.
https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore/tree/develop/samples

Comment: I am consuming a SOAP Service. But, i got it.